# Project with path 'sdk' could not be found in project 'projectName'

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I wrote a Tappay plugin, but I failed to use it.
Please help me, thanks a lot!!

https://pub.dev/packages/tappayflutter

[Here's my android error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDURs.png)

[Here's my xcode error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8QCEJ.png)

Here's my pubspec.yaml

```
description: A Flutter framework builded by Tung.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  http: ^0.12.0+4
  share: ^0.6.3+6
  tappayflutter: ^0.0.7
  flutter_tappay: ^0.3.0+2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:

  uses-material-design: true
```

Comment: what do you mean by wrote a Tappay plugin?

Comment: @RajuKomati Tappay is a third party payment company. I wrote a plugin to develop on Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

inside you root dir of project create `local.properties` file inside it put your sdk path like this :

```
sdk.dir=/Users/tusharpandey/Library/Android/sdk
```